# vba/excel - How to use RC notation to copy formula from different sheet while maintaining relative references

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to copy a formula from another sheet ("SCE_Tables") to a central sheet ("Main"). "SCE_Tables" holds reference tables that I am copying over to main, based on selections from a form that the user fills out.

The formula in "SCE_Tables", uses RC-notation to subtract values from columns 2 to the left ('Prebill'), and 1 to the left ('Post BESS Bill') of the cells in the 'BESS Savings' column:
In the highlighted cell below:

Formula:
`=RC[-2]-RC[-1]`
. This cell is at Row 15, Column 6

[image: sce_table_demo]

The issue arises when I try to fill the "Main" sheet range with these tables. The "Main" sheet range where these tables go have the same format as the reference tables:
The highlighted cell below (on the "Main" sheet), is at Row 21, Column 18. The formula in this cell is:

Formula:
`=R[-6]C[-14]-R[-6]C[-13]`

[image]

The RC reference that is copied over to the "Main" sheet converts the RC reference back to that in the "SCE_Tables" sheet, resulting in the formula trying to calculate:

`(R15, C4) - (R15, C5)`
on the main sheet, when my desired formula is:

`(R21, C16) - (R21, C15)`

Is there a way I dynamically create a formula that calculates the difference between the cells 2 to the left and 1 to the left of the cell in the "Main" sheet?

Edit: Including some of my VBA code
To process the ListBox selections:

```
Public Sub FormatListboxSelections(ByVal selectionNameArray As Variant)
    testInt = 0

    'Entire possible area for tables
    Dim tableRange As Range
    Set tableRange = Range("TableRange")
    Dim SDR As Range
    Set SDR = Range("ScenarioDetailsRange")
    
    
    'Electricity Provider
    Dim i As Integer, elecProvider As String
    elecProvider = Range("input_electricity_provider").Value
    
    'Clear range
    tableRange.ClearContents
    SDR.ClearContents
    
    Dim currRow As Integer, leftCol As Integer, startingCell As Range
    currRow = 1
    
    'Loop through all selections
    For i = LBound(selectionNameArray) To UBound(selectionNameArray)
        Dim selectionTableObj As Variant
        
        Dim scenario As String
        scenario = selectionNameArray(i)
        'If arr(i) == 0, we've reached end of the selected values
        If Len(scenario) = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Exiting loop at index " & i
            Exit For
        Else
            'Check for each scenario type
            'PV only scenario
            If scenario = "PV Only" Then
                Set selectionTableObj = HandlePVOnly(electricityProvider:=elecProvider, scenario:=scenario)
            ElseIf scenario = "2hr Only" Or scenario = "4hr Only" Then
                Set selectionTableObj = HandleBESSOnly(electricityProvider:=elecProvider, scenario:=scenario)
            Else
                Set selectionTableObj = HandleComboScenario(electricityProvider:=elecProvider, scenario:=scenario)
            End If
        selectionTableObj.UpdateAllFields
        testInt = testInt + 1
        End If
        
        Dim x As Integer
        'Iterate through all rows in the selected table
        For x = 1 To selectionTableObj.m_table.Rows.Count
            Dim dummy As Variant
            Set dummy = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(selectionTableObj.m_table.Rows, x, 0)
            Dim selectionTableRow As Variant
            Set selectionTableRow = selectionTableObj.m_table.Rows(x)
            
            'Update single row
            '***HERE IS WHERE THE SELECTED TABLES GET WRITTEN TO THE MAIN 
            'WORKSHEET***
            Dim j As Integer
            For j = 1 To dummy.Columns.Count
                tableRange(currRow, j).Formula = dummy(1, j).Formula
            Next j
        
            'increment currRow
            currRow = currRow + 1
        
        Next x
        
    Next
    
    'If full selection, also show respective extra inputs
    If UBound(selectionNameArray) = 7 Then
        PopulateExtraInputs elecProvider
    End If
End Sub
```

To handle BESS scenarios (one of 3 scenario types the user can select with the form), I use a Factory module and call the 'InitiateProperties' subroutine in the BESSScenarioTable class module:

```
Public Function CreateBESSScenarioTable(ByVal table As Range, scenario As String, scenarioDetailsArray As Variant, tableLength As Integer, ByVal result As ScenarioResult, tariffs As Variant)
    Set CreateBESSScenarioTable = New BESSScenarioTable
    CreateBESSScenarioTable.InitiateProperties table:=table, scenario:=scenario, scenarioDetailsArray:=scenarioDetailsArray, tableLength:=tableLength, result:=result, tariffs:=tariffs
End Function
```

```
'Constructor
Public Sub InitiateProperties(table As Range, scenario As String, scenarioDetailsArray As Variant, tableLength As Integer, result As ScenarioResult, tariffs As Variant)
    Set m_table = table
    'Using Formula instead of Value to capture column relationships in "Source of Truth" tables (PGE_Tables, SDGE_Tables, SCE_Tables worksheets)
    Debug.Print "Address: " & m_table.address
    Dim xc As Integer, yc As Integer
    For xc = 1 To m_table.Rows.Count
        For yc = 1 To m_table.Columns.Count
            Debug.Print "(" & xc & ", " & yc & ") - Formula: " & m_table.Cells(xc, yc).Formula
        Next yc
    Next xc
    m_table.FormulaR1C1 = table.FormulaR1C1
    m_scenario = scenario
    m_scenarioDetailsArray = scenarioDetailsArray
    m_tableLength = tableLength
    Set m_result = result
    m_tariffs = tariffs
End Sub
```

Comment: If you're using VBA then it helps to include your code in your post.  If you're not using VBA then it would be helpful to explain exactly how you get the results you're describing.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for the suggestion - i've updated the post with relevant code chunks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - turns out in my VBA code where I was copying the table over, I needed to use `tableRange(currRow, j).FormulaR1C1 = dummy(1, j).FormulaR1C1`, instead of what I had before: `tableRange(currRow, j).Formula = dummy(1, j).Formula`

This link was helpful in learning about the different notations Excel uses: https://powerspreadsheets.com/r1c1-formular1c1-vba/